Ardalis.Result package - not able to return custom error object
Swagger is generating below documentation.

In my code, I am returning ValidationError object and it's not returning that.

Here is the ValidationError class.

Is this anything wrong with my mapping or do I have to write down my own TranslateResultToActionResult attribute to achieve it?
